# What exactly is oxidation number with regards to [Fe(CN)6]-4

Tags: transition-metals, oxidation-state

I read that $\ce{Fe}$ has an oxidation state of $+2$ in $\ce{[Fe(CN)6]^{4-}}$. Does that mean $\ce{Fe}$ gives away $2$ electrons? Doesn't $\ce{(CN)6}$ form coordination bonds with $\ce{Fe}$ meaning $\ce{Fe}$ should have a negative oxidation number?

Comment: Why should coordination bonds affect the oxidation state of iron?  E.g. the oxidation state of Cu^2+ and CuCl4^2- is the same.

Comment: Please use LaTeX to edit the chemical formula of compounds . See https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/faq-how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange/86#4726 especially section 3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL, DR: The problem is with formal charge, not oxidation state; but there is no paradox with either when chemists consider a more complete picture of the bonding in transition-metal complexes.

Contrary to the premise in the question, coordinate-covalent bonding need not affect oxidation state. Consider the ammonia molecule, $\ce{NH3}$, accepting a proton to form $\ce{NH4^+}$. The nitrogen atom provides both electrons to bond with the additional hydrogen, but the electrons remain polarized towards the nitrogen like the original $\ce{N - H}$ bonds. As a result the nitrogen retains the same oxidation state, -3, in both $\ce{NH3}$ and $\ce{NH4^+}$. Similarly, iron in $\ce{Fe(CN)6^{4-}}$ has the same +2 oxidation state as in "bare" $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$.

What does change with coordinate-covalent bonding is formal charge. Opposite to the convention used for oxidation states, formal charging regards covalent bonds as nonpolar even where that is far from true. So when the nitrogen in ammonia uses its nonbonding pair to accept a proton, it picks up a positive formal charge. If we regard the incoming proton as bare, then that hydrogen atom takes the  opposing drop in formal charge from +1 to zero. If the proton is regarded as coming from a more usual acid, let us say $\ce{H3O^+}$, then a bond between oxygen and hydrogen is also broken and thus the oxygen in the original hydronium ion takes the formal drop from +1 to zero.

This is all well and good for the nonmetallic species given above, where only a single coordinate-covalent bond is formed and chemiats are comfortable with most nometal atoms having either one positive or one negative formal charge. With transition metal complexes, however, multiple coordinate-covalent bonds appear and the metal may take a multiple negative formal charge even though it's oxidation state is positive. Iron in $\ce{Fe(CN)6^{4-}}$ has an oxidation state of +2 but apparently a formal charge of -4. Negative formal charges on metal atoms, which hold their valence electrons only loosely even when neutral, is an uncomfortable situation which most chemist circumvent in one of two ways.

**You're not going anywhere!**

One possibility with relatively electronegative atoms bonded to the metal, like chloride ligands, the bonding might be considered essentially ionic. The relatively normal oxidation state is thus more relevant to the molecular structure than the problematic formal charge.

**A taste of your own medicine**

The second possibility is seen with many carbon-based ligands that have pi bonding, like cyanide ion and the most common organic ligands. In such cases the pi antibonding orbitals in the ligand can overlap the $d$ electrons on the metal and pi-electton transfer can occur. This weakens the pi bonding in the ligand but in exchange, creates metal-ligand pi bonding. Ligands with this property are called **pi acceptors**. If this is rendered as contributing Lewis structures, it is seen as a **delocalization** of the pi bonding:

$\ce{\overset{-}{Fe} - C#N <-> Fe=C=\overset{-}{N}}$

As the name "pi acceptor" implies, metal electrons in this interaction are regarded as coming from the metal, canceling out the sigma electrons coming from the ligand. As the overset charges above indicate, this removes the paradoxical negative formal charges from the metal and sends them to the more natural home of more electronegative ligand atoms.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Reading this cleared this doubt and other queries I had.

Comment: You may want to consider accepting this answer if you think it helps you. Doing so is proper etiquette and with the q closed you may not get anything much better. Stay safe!